# Can there be content sent the a vanilla Drupal 8 sites' views that isn't a node?

Tags: views, 8

Is it possible to add content into views that is not searchable from google? I am trying to find out if the content sent to views has to be of a type node. (I think there are other modules for importing xml into views and such, but I am asking for just the vanilla views)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't import things into a View; you configure a View with certain criteria, and that basically runs a query against the database, the results of which are formatted and rendered according to the rest of the View config.

It's not restricted to nodes, many entity types and pseudo-entity types can be queried, as Views is very extensible.

You mention *importing xml into views* - in reality that happens by 2 separate processes - importing XML and creating content/entities from it, then setting up a View to display that content.

Don't think of a View as a container. It's essentially a sophisticated HTML report builder that knows how to get and format Drupal data.